# diy 110 volt tester

Tags: voltage, resistors

I want to copy a 110volt tester I made in the 7th grade.
It consists of one small bulb and I believe one resistor.
Both fit inside a small tube(transparent gas line) with two leads coming out.  I need to know the bulb voltage and the size of resistor.

Answer (score 3):

We have of course no way of knowing what you did in 7th grade.  However, from the description is was probably a neon bulb with series resistor.

Common neon bulbs fire at around 70-90 volts.  That means they look like a open circuit until the neon is ionized, then suddenly become low impedance.  They stay low impedance as long as some minimum current is maintained.  The resistor is to limit the current after the neon trips.

The bulb voltage is what it is.  As long as it is somewhat less than the peak of the line voltage the bulb will fire reliably.  Then you look at the bulb datasheet and see what it's maximum allowed current is.  Size the resistor so that current is not exceeded even at the peak of the line cycle with some margin.  If you don't need as much brightness you can use a larger resistor, but you have to consider the minimum sustaining current too.  That is the current required to keep the neon ionized.

Comment: @Russell - Did you not intend the formula to be: (Vline-Vbulb)^2 / Resistance ?

Comment: Resistor MUST be rated to withstand the VOLTAGE of the line (that your days may be long on the face of the land). Resistor wattage must be sensibly larger than (Vline-Vbulb_operating)^2 / Resistance. Putting Vbulb_operating at 0 for this calculation is safest.

Comment: @MichaelKaras - Yes - thanks - deleted and posted new version as cannot edit after a few minutes.